# Loading page faster by storing keys into sessions golang

Tags: google-app-engine, session, twitter, go

I am trying to load dynamic page faster. I am making twitter clone as a learning assignment. I am following below approach

1. When somebody tweets, store the tweet in datastore and safe the same in memcache { key.string(), json.Marshal(tweet) }
2. I push the tweet in User home time line. The home time line is a []*datastore.Key, which is stored in user session (which get copied in memcache and then in DB).
3. When user open her homepage, the homepage try to get the Keys from session, if not found then it make a datastore query.
4. Once i get the keys I fetch the tweets from memcache (if not then from db)

I am stuck at step 3.

In first case I am getting the correct information but in string slices (not in []*datastore.Key).

In second case I getting this error

> 2016/09/03 17:23:42 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:47104: interface
>   conversion: interface is []interface {}, not []datastore.Key

Kindly help me where I am going wrong and is there a better way.

case 1

```
func GetKeys(req *http.Request, vars ...string) []interface{} {
    //GetKeys - get the keys
    s, _ := GetGSession(req)
    var flashes []interface{}
    key := internalKey
    if len(vars) > 0 {
        key = vars[0]
    }

    if v, ok := s.Values[key]; ok {
        // Drop the flashes and return it.
        //  delete(s.Values, key)
        flashes = v.([]interface{})
    }
    return flashes
}
```

Case2

```
//GetHTLKeys - get the hometimeline keys
func GetHTLKeys(req *http.Request, vars ...string) []datastore.Key {
    s, _ := GetGSession(req)

    var keyList []datastore.Key

    key := internalKey
    if len(vars) > 0 {
        key = vars[0]
    }

    if v, ok := s.Values[key]; ok {
        keyList = v.([]datastore.Key)
    }
    return keyList
}
```

Comment: How have you defined `GetGSession`?

Comment: That is a normal Gorilla session..   'code' //GetGSession -
func GetGSession(req *http.Request) (session *sessions.Session, err error) {

 session, err = mcdstore.Get(req, "secondSession")
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }
 return session, err
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you can't assert an `[]interface{}` is a `[]datastore.Key`. This is because they are different.
What you can do at this point, is type assert `v` to a `[]interface{}` then loop through the slice and type assert each element.

Here is an example demonstrating this ([playground version](https://play.golang.org/p/IFEzOQsoyo)):

```
type I interface {
    I()
}

type S struct{}

func (s S) I() {
    fmt.Println("S implements the I interface")
}

// Represents you getting something out of the session
func f(s S) interface{} {
    return []interface{}{s}
}

func main() {
    v := f(S{})

    //v2 := v.([]I) would panic like in your example.

    v2, ok := v.([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        // handle having a non []interface{} as a value
    }
    for _, v3 := range v2 {
        v4, ok := v3.(I)
        if !ok {
            // handle having a non-I in the slice
        }
        v4.I() //you definitely have an I here 
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to this, so unable to execute your suggestion. I getting null value in v4.

Comment: <code> 'type S struct { datastore.Key}
func (s S) I() { fmt.Println("S implements the I interface") }
func f(s S) interface{} { return []interface{}{s} }
func GetHTLKeysTypeAssert(req *http.Request, vars ...string) []interface{} {
 ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
 s, _ := GetGSession(req)
 v := f(S{})
 key := internalKey
 var ok bool
 if v, ok = s.Values[key]; ok {
  v2, ok1 := v.([]interface{})
  if !ok1 {//err}
   for _, v3 := range v2 { v4, ok2 := v3.(I)
   if !ok {//err} log.Infof(ctx, "v4 %+v", v4)
 } return v2 }' </code>

Comment: So if v4 is nil, it means what you had in v3 wasn't of the interface you were expecting, or it had a nil value to begin with. did you get the log from line 49?

Comment: Hi Dean, ya there was a typo on line 48 that is why didn't catch the null earlier. However, I changed the implementation. Instead of using interface, I changed everything to []datastore.Key and it working fine now. Will explore why it didn't work for interface. Thanks for all your help.